# Thread safety between subsequent calls of an Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor

Tags: java, thread-safety, executorservice

I have a question regarding using a single threaded executor. Since it reuses the same thread, does that means that If I modify an object state in one submit call, can I assume that another modification of that object state in subsequent calls of submit are thread safe? Let me give a toy example...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final A a = new Main().new A();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Callable<Integer> callable = new Callable<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                return a.modifyState();
            }
        };

        /* first call */
        Future<Integer> result = executor.submit(callable);
        result.get();

        /* second call */
        result = executor.submit(callable);
        int fin = result.get();
        System.out.println(fin);

        executor.shutdown();
    }

    class A {

        private int state;

        public int modifyState() {
            return ++state;
        }

        public int getState() {
            return state;
        }

    }
}
```

So I am sharing object A. I submit a callable and modify it's state first ( see /* first call */ ). I  then do another submit call, modify again A state. (/* second call */).Now my big question

Is it safe to say that, since it's the same thread, the second submit call will see A.state as being 1? Or could it see it as being 0 in some cases too?

So basically I am asking if it's safe to modify variables that are not marked as volatile/accessed from synchronized blocks in subsequent submit calls of a single thread executor?, since it reuses the same thread

What exactly does thread reusing means regarding executors? Is it really the same thread at OS level in the case of an single thread executor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() gives you thread safety by guaranteeing only one thread running at a time. It also gives you grantee about visibility which means any state change during one thread execution will be visible to next thread execution.

Answer (score 5):

It actually doesn't matter that it is single threaded. The javadoc of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) states:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get().

Comment: Let me see If I understood this correctly... so basically a synchronization from/to main memory occurs so no volatile/synchronize need?

Comment: @user3030447 +1 The executing thread trips over a few memory barriers just to see a thread safe view of the execution queue. This ensures any previous actions have a consistent view.

Comment: But what if we didn't have the future.get calls? Would it be thread safe?

Comment: @user3030447 it wouldn't with a generic executor service (because the tasks could be executed concurrently and `A` is not thread safe). But with a single threaded executor you would be fine - cf the javadoc: "*Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially*". Sequentially has a specific meaning in the context of the Java Memory Model and basically guarantees program order.

Comment: But is this guaranteed because the code is executed sequentially, or because the same thread is reused and hence the variables are modified on the same thread? Also if you would modify A state sequentially but from different threads, it's still okay right? Where can I read more about sequential execution and memeory model in java?

Comment: @user3030447 Yes it will reuse the same thread, unless that thread dies, in which case it will create a new one but ensure that it is transparent and thread safe from your perspective. If you modify A from a different thread it is ***not*** ok because A is not thread safe.

Comment: @user3030447 About sequential consistency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3